# How to I access the indexed values of a Tuple?

Tags: c#, tuples

Consider the following code from another StackOverflow question:

```
public (double, string) AdjustFileSize(long fileSizeInBytes)
{
    var names = {"BYTES", "KB", "MB", "GB"};

    double sizeResult = fileSizeInBytes * 1.0;
    int nameIndex = 0;
    while (sizeResult > 1024 && nameIndex < names.Length)
    {
        sizeResult /= 1024; 
        nameIndex++;
    }

    return (sizeResult, names[nameIndex]);
}
```

What I don't understand about Tuples is that I feel in the calling method I should be able get back the KB, MB or GB values. But, I don't know how.

```
FileSize = filesize.Item1.ToString("F"),
```

All I get back is the KB filesize value, how do I access the other numeric values?

Comment: You can do something like `var (size, unit) = AdjustFileSize(fileSizeInBytes);`. Maybe that's what you are looking for?

Comment: Function will not return size for all units, but for only one. You need to change function to return corresponding sizes for every unit

Answer (score 1):

You can specify name in the result declaration:

```cs
public (double size, string unit) AdjustFileSize(...)
```

Then:

```cs
var filesize = AdjustFileSize(...);
FileSize = filesize.size.ToString("F");
FileUnit = filesize.unit;
```

The declared names take precedence over `Item1`, `Item2` etc, but: they *only exist* in the outbound call path (via attributes); they can't be discovered via reflection on the result (`filesize`) itself.

Answer (score 1):

Function returns only one size for one appropriate unit.

> how do I access the other numeric values?

Change function to return size for all units

```
public class FileSize
{
    private readonly double _bytes;

    public double Bytes => _bytes;
    public double Kb => _bytes / 1024;
    public double Mb => Kb / 1024;
    public double Gb => Mb / 1024;

    public FileSize(long size)
    {
        _bytes = size * 1.0
    }
}

// Usage

var size = new FileSize(120000);
size.Bytes; // 120000
size.Kb; // 120
size.Mb; // 0.12
```

I would suggest to use class to encapsulate behaviour with associated value.

Answer (score 0):

This function returns a tuple consisting of a single string, not a string array - as one of the types.

The string is extracted from the array at this point: `names[nameIndex]`. The scope of said array is limited to the function. It simply does not "exist" outside the funciton brackets (or rather there is no way for you to tell the compiler you want to access it; existence is a wierd thing in .NET). Same as `sizeResult` and `nameIndex`.

If you want a string array as return, use string[] as type. If you want to access that array elsewhere, do not make it only function scope. Personally I would propably define it as a static readonly for this class. Or much more likely a Enumeration.

But the whole *purpose* of this function is to get you the one string value you want - from an array you can not access - plus shifting the whole number to the left accordingly. So that would not even be in the range of what this code is about.